# Long time behavior of the heat equation on R

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, asymptotics, linear-pde, fa.functional-analysis, differential-equations

Let $\mu\in\mathcal{S}'(R)$ be a Schwartz distribution. The solution of a heat equation with $\mu$ as the initial data is

$$
u(t,x)= \int_R \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2t}}}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \mu(d y)
$$

You can assume that $\mu$ is non-negative, i.e., a measure on $R$.

The problem is how $u(t,x)$ behaves for $x$ fixed as $t\rightarrow\infty$. I guess that it might not increase too fast for large $t$, e.g., it does not increase like $e^t$. Do anyone have any idea?

Thank you very much in advance!

EDIT:
Here is one try: 
If we smooth $\mu$ by a test function to get say $\mu_n$, then $\mu_n$ is a smooth function with at most certain polynomial increase. However, the degree of the domination polynomial might depend on $n$...

Comment: Simple case: When $\mu$ is a delta function, you have an exact formula.

Comment: @Gerald Edgar, Yes, in the delta initial case, $u(t,x)$ decays like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$. That's why I guess that for a general initial data, the solution still decays. Actually, what I need is $u(t,x)$ does not increase too fast.

Comment: I don't think it needs to decrease.  For instance if $\mu$ is simply Lebesgue measure, then $u(x,t)\equiv 1$, no?

Comment: @Peter Luthy, yes. you are right. It might have at most some polynormial increase?


Comment: If μ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure, then the density should be dominated by some polynomial. Certainly in that case, the integral will grow at most like some power of t: in particular I believe it should grow like $t^{d/2}$, where d is the degree of the polynomial bound for the density function.

Comment: @Peter Luthy, thank you for the comments. How about the general Schwartz distribution?

Comment: If $\mu$ is a probability measure, then it should still decrease like $1/\sqrt{t}$.  This is related to Brownian motion in the plane.

Comment: @Prof. Gerald Edgar, Thank you very much for the comments. Indeed, my problem is for a general initial data $\mu$ in Schwartz distribution space. :-)


Comment: Anand, even if your initial data is only a distribution, it is smooth for any positive time. So any conclusion about long time behavior given smooth initial data applies just as well to initial data that is only a distribution.

Comment: @Prof. Deane Yang, Thank you. Intuitively it likes that. I totally agree. But to write a rigorous proof, the answer by Andrew seems better. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denote $\Gamma(x,t)$ the fundamental solution of the heat equation form the integral. By the theorem of L. Schwarz for any $\mu\in S'(S)$ there is a number $m\in \mathbb N$ and $C>0$ such that $$|u(x,t)|=|(\mu,\Gamma(t,\cdot))|\le C\|\Gamma(t,\cdot)\|_m,$$ where
$
\|\varphi\|_m=$

$\sup_{\alpha \le m,\  x \in \mathbb R}(1+|x|)^m |\partial^\alpha \varphi(x)|.
$

It is straightforward to obtain, as it is said in the comments, that the $u$ increases at most polynomially. Namely, it is known that $$|\partial_x^k \Gamma(t,x)|\le C_k t^{-(k+1)/2}e^{-c_k x^2/t}.\ $$ From here it is easy to get $$|x^m \partial_x^k \Gamma(t,x)|\le C_{k,m} t^{(m-k-1)/2}e^{-c_{k,m} x^2/t},$$ since $|y|^m e^{-c y} \le C_m$. Putting $y=x^2/t\ $ we have $|x|^m e^{-c x^2/t}\le t^{m/2}e^{-c x^2/2t}$.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. You remind me using the definition of the tempered distribution. A minor improvement is that $u(x,t)=|(\mu,\Gamma(t,x-\cdot))|\le C||\Gamma(t,x-\cdot)||_m$. I am now checking the rests. Thanks again for your help! :-)

Comment: @Anand Yes, you are right. The answer for convolution is the same since $$\sup_{y\in\mathbb R}|y^m \partial_x^k \Gamma(t,x-y)|\le C \sup_{y\in\mathbb R} (|x|^m+|x-y|^m)\partial_x^k \Gamma(t,x-y)|\ldots$$